# Is sex chatting on Facebook zina?

Tags: sex, zina, internet

When I was in the second year of college, I used to sex chat with a random man. Now, I feel guilty about it. Did I commit zina? And what should I do about it? I blocked him and deleted that account.

Comment: Please take the time to write your question clearly and legibly.  We as a site expect posts to be written to a professional standard of quality, poor grammar and especially excessive use of text-speak are highly discouraged here.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that you have done a bad and haram practice via Facebook. But it is not counted as Zina practice, since there is a specific introduction for Zina (you can see the site below concerning the explanation of Zina, of course it is in Farsi and France. 
http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa8288 
http://www.islamquest.net/fr/archive/question/fa8288 )

on the other hand, as you inquired “what to do”, So the main step would be related to repentance and promising not to repeat it (or other similar sins) at all.

You’d better notice to the following verse concerning repentance.

> [1]"هُوَ الَّذِی یَقْبَلُ التَّوْبَةَ عَنْ عِبادِهِ وَ یَعْفُوا عَنِ
>   السَّیِّئاتِ"
>
> "It is He who accepts the repentance of His servants, and excuses
>   their misdeeds." (Shura: 25.)

The truth of repentance (التوبه) is related to regret and remorse for committing sins (that sinner people have done…) and this entails the decision to avoid committing sins in the future and compensate for those which could be made up for. Reciting (saying) 'Istiqfar' (استغفار) would be a verbalization of such a decision and regret. In this light the fundamental elements of repentance ((التوبه shortly are as following:

- Avoiding committing (doing) sins
- Having regret and remorse
- Deciding (as a real decision) not to return to sins in the future
  (since now till later)
- Compensating for our past (for bad things which have done)
- Istiqfar ((استغفار

On the other hand, doing extraordinary good acts which would be the cause of forgiveness of previous misdeeds. regarding this issue, the Quran mentions:

> إِنَّ الْحَسَناتِ یُذْهِبْنَ السَّیِّئاتِ
>
> Indeed good deeds efface misdeeds (Hud:114.)

**References:**

http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa860

http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa8288

Answer (score -1):

i have heard phrases "zina of eye", "zina of feet", so i am not sure it is not zina.

i am sorry i am lazy to search for proofs.

i do not want to upvote nor favorite nor bookmark this, i choose better to write this simple answer. i could comment as it is recommended in comment to another simple answer here. is not answering without proofs prohibited? i do not see rules for answering here, nor link to that. i think you/sobebody can answer this in comment.

but ok, i google it, i see there are some texts : https://www.google.com/search?q=zina+of+eye .

i think probably there are degrees of meanings for words, words can be used almost metaphorically and metaphorically, and even inside boundary, which is between "100%" meaning and metaphorical meanings, meanings are sorted by their directness for the word, as you can see in dictionaries. and probably the boundary might be quite unclear for some words. i assume, this usage of word "zina" is at unclear boundary of meanings of that word.

Comment: http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer